# historical imagery plugin of google earth in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, google-earth

i want to call google earth historical imagery function using openlayers. is it possible that we can call google earth functions in openlayers? I have added google map using open layers. now I want show historical imagery like google earth. I did not find any clear answer yet.

```js
const map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }) })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([69.3451, 30.392053]),
            zoom: 5.7
          })
});
```